# HTML - Datafilters and Isotopes

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it would be possible for me to make some sort of script so when you refresh the page it doesn't just goto the default screen, it will goto whatever data-filter you have open.

I was hoping to go a bit more advanced so I could make outside links open a page straight to a data filter. Any idea how I could do this? I'm not even sure where to start, I tried googling about it but it kept showing up with stuff unrelated. This might not even be possible and that might be why but I figured I might as well try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just create an HTML `<a name="my_middle_of_page_link">` anchor tag in your document.

Then, to link to it, just use `<a href="mypage/my_middle_of_page_link">`.

Here are some simple examples: [HTML Links](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp)

Comment: The way my document is setup is that I name a certain section of the website for example "contact". But when you goto the homepage that won't show as its hidden but if you click the content button that triggers to open the data-filter "contact" it will show up. Would I just put <a name="my_middle_of_page_link"> before the class starts for the contact part and then close the a tag after the content? Because that didn't work.